# Making list of adjacent node pairs from Cube-formatted line file (using Python)

Tags: python, data-modeling

My files are formatted like this:

```
LINE NAME="FirstLine", MODE=15, ONEWAY=T, HEADWAY[1]=20, HEADWAY[2]=30,
     HEADWAY[3]=20, HEADWAY[4]=30, HEADWAY[5]=30, VEHICLETYPE=2,
     XYSPEED=20, N=-20609, -22042, -20600, 20601, 22839, 22838,
     -20602, -20607, -20606, -20605, -20896, -20895, -20897, 20898,
     -20899, -20905, -20906, -20910, 21104, -20911, -20912, 25065,
     -21375
LINE NAME="SecondLine", MODE=15, ONEWAY=T, HEADWAY[1]=25, HEADWAY[2]=35,
[ETC]
```

I need to extract the lists of numbers that come after `N=` (one list for each `N=`), get rid of the minus-signs, and append each pair of adjacent numbers (e.g. `[[20609, 22042], [22042, 20600]]`) into a list of pairs. The major sticking part for Python-noob me is just extracting the lists of numbers as the first step (i.e. making what comes after each `N=` a list of its own).

If Python lists aren't ordered, I may have to make the lists strings and write each one as a line in a new file.

Comment: Python lists are ordered. What is the description of this Cube format you present?

Comment: Cube is transportation modeling software.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using the find method for `LINE` and `N=`. Finding `LINE` would increase an index and make a new item in a dictionary corresponding to that index. Finding `N=` would give the "definition" to that item in the dictionary -- a list with a single string element. Then for each item in the dictionary, I stripped spaces, replaced the `-` with `''` (i.e. nothing), and used the split method with argument `','` to cut up the lists.

Then I zipped those lists `Li[:-1]` into themselves `Li[1:]` to get the adjacent-node pairs I needed.

Probably no one will ever find this useful (and I know it's probably convoluted), but here's my code:

```
with open(path + filename) as f:
    i = 0
    L = {}
    for line in f:
        existL = line.find("LINE")
        existN = line.find("N=")

        if existL > -1:
            i = i + 1
            L["Line" + str(i)] = []

        if existN > -1:
            go = 0
            while go == 0:
                txtNodes = line[line.rfind('=')+1:].strip()
                nodes = txtNodes.split(',')

                for node in nodes:
                    node = node.strip()
                    node = node.replace('-','')
                    if len(node) > 3:
                        L["Line" + str(i)].append(node)

                try:
                    line = f.next()
                    if line.find("LINE") > -1:
                        go = go + 1
                        i = i + 1
                        L["Line" + str(i)] = []
                except:
                    go = go + 1

Li = []
while i > 1:
    L1 = L["Line" + str(i)][:-1]
    L2 = L["Line" + str(i)][1:]
    Lx = zip(L1,L2)

    i = i-1
    Li.extend(Lx)
```

I hate when people come to forums and don't follow up, so here's my follow-up. Sorry for posting in the wrong place initially.